# More connections number in MySQL when I use the BoneCP in Playframework? Any system connection created for BoneCP?

Tags: mysql, playframework-2.0, connection-pooling, bonecp

I try to configure the settings of BoneCP in my project which is using the playframework.

e.g.

```
db.server.partitionCount=1
db.server.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.server.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
```

When I using this MySQL to check the current connection numbers:

```
>show processlist
```

I expected only 5 connections are created for my project.

But I can see 10 connections.

Why? Any system connections are created for BoneCP?

Thanks,
Nannan

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the reason, there is nothing wrong in the BoneCP, and there is no system or deamon connections for it.

I can see 10, it is  because there is another thread also tries to connect the DB.

Thanks,
Nannan